# Excluding child records from entity objects c#

Tags: frameworks, linq-to-entities, entity

I am having an issue with writing a query to exclude records from entity framework child objects.
My query

```
var response = db.USER_PROFILE.Where(x =>
            x.IPAD_SERIAL_NUMBER == id
            && x.ACTIVE_FLAG == 1
            && x.USER_BRAND.Any(y => y.ACTIVE_FLAG == 1)
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Returned result

One USER_PROFILE object with

Two USER_BRAND objects

USER_BRAND - ACTIVE_FLAG = 1

USER_BRAND - ACTIVE_FLAG = 0

I don't want to return a record with ACTIVE_FLAG = 0 in the collection.
How do I do easily that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way

```
var query = db.USER_PROFILE
            .Select(x=> new 
            {
                User = x,
                UserBrands = x.USER_BRAND.Where(y=> y.ACTIVE_FLAG == 1)
                    .Select(a=> new 
                    { 
                        UserBrand = a, 
                        Brand = a.BRAND
                    }),
            });

var filtered = query.Select(x=> x.User);
```